# Angular 7 Platform-Browser-Dynamic (intermediate value).share is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, rxjs, angular7

I have been updating our Angular 5 build to 7 and after installing webpack 4, rxjs 6.3.3 and angular 7.0.3 as well as taking care of dependencies I have gotten the bundle to compile. However this hard to trace error is occurring when it tries to bind the app component to it's selector.

`t_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value).share is not a function  at new t (platform-browser-dynamic.js:314)`

Here is my main.ts file ( the file that bootstraps my component ) :

```
import { tap, mapTo, share } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform- 
browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Here is my vendor.ts file:

```
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/forms';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';
import '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import 'ngx-scrollspy';

import 'rxjs/operators/map';
import 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/operators/share';
```

Here are the generated head script imports (seems like the proper order):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="0.chunk.js" defer> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js" defer></script></head>
```

and finally here are the relevant parts of the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"@angular/animations": "7.0.4",
"@angular/cli": "7.0.6",
"@angular/common": "7.0.4",
"@angular/compiler": "7.0.4",
"@angular/core": "7.0.4",
"@angular/forms": "7.0.4",
"@angular/http": "7.0.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.0.4",
"@angular/platform-server": "7.0.4",
"@angular/router": "7.0.4",
"@angular/upgrade": "7.0.4",
...
"rxjs": "6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
...
"devDependencies": {
...
"@ngtools/webpack": "7.0.6",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
...
"typescript": "3.1.1",
"webpack": "4.26.0",
"webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "3.4.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.1.10",
"webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
"webpack-merge": "1.0.1"
...
}
```

Update: I have tried using the rxjs linter found here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-tslint and it results in 'Cannot find any possible migrations'. So I assume I migrated properly.

Comment: At the time of this post the issue was RXJS 6.3.3 does not seem to play well with Angular. I had to downgrade for now to 6.2.2. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this post the issue was RXJS 6.3.3 does not seem to play well with Angular. I had to downgrade for now to 6.2.2. This solved my issue.

```
 "dependencies": {
   ...
   "rxjs": "6.2.2",
   "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
   ...
 }
```